# Neo4j Bloom crashing when selecting 'Create node' option in version 4.4.4 - suspected bug

Tags: neo4j, bloom

"I am experiencing issues with Neo4j Bloom and am unable to create anything directly from it. When I click on a scene to choose the option 'Create node', the application crashes. I suspect there is a bug. I have attempted to accept any suggested updates, but this has not resolved the problem. I am currently using version 4.4.4. Is there a solution to this issue that does not require me to change the version?

Accepted any suggested updates.
The bug is still existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the bloom and neo4j versions and now the problem is resolved.
I am running bloom from neo4j desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the version of Bloom you are using would be very helpful.  How are you running Bloom?  From a Web Browser e.g. Chrome, or Neo4j Desktop?  Is there a message from the crash?  I'll suggest that 4.4.4 is very old, and the upgrade path from 4.4.4 to 4.4.latest is pretty straightforward.